# C# / C++ Interop: How to modify class in C++ memory from C#

Tags: c#, c++, mono, interop

I'm including a C# DLL in my C++ project, and I want both to be able to edit the same struct or class in memory easily I could use functions to set/get the members or struct, but I think this would have a lot more overhead and be cumbersome. I'd rather be able to edit the member variables directly, mapping the memory of the C# side to match the C++ side.

I'm using Mono to manage the C# from C++ but I'm not sure this is important.

This is my attempt at doing so, but any changes in C# only affect the C# struct. How can I fix this?

C++ (Unmanaged) Code:

```
#ifdef ENGINE_CORE
    #define ENGINE_CORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define ENGINE_CORE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct TestStruct {
    int myElement = 4;
};

TestStruct testStruct;

extern "C" {
    ENGINE_CORE_API void GetTestStruct(TestStruct** transf) {
        *transf = &testStruct;
    }
}
```

C# (Managed) Code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class TestStruct {
    public int myElement;
};

public class Example {
    // Called in a loop:
    public void OnUpdate() {
        GetTestStruct(out TestStruct testStruct);
        testStruct.myElement += 2;
        Logger.Print($"Int: {testStruct.myElement}");
    }

    #region DllImports
    [DllImport("EngineCore")]
    static extern void GetTestStruct([Out] out TestStruct comp);
    #endregion
}
```

Output:

```
[2022-02-26 00:02:54.959] [Debug Logger] [info] Int: 6
[2022-02-26 00:02:55.220] [Debug Logger] [info] Int: 6
[2022-02-26 00:02:55.234] [Debug Logger] [info] Int: 6
```

Expected Output:

```
[2022-02-26 00:02:54.959] [Debug Logger] [info] Int: 6
[2022-02-26 00:02:55.220] [Debug Logger] [info] Int: 8
[2022-02-26 00:02:55.234] [Debug Logger] [info] Int: 10
```

Comment: Your best bet to do this is, imo, is to do C# -> c++/cli -> c++. That is going to give you the cleanest easiest way since in the middle layer you have easy and unrestricted access to pointers from c++ while still having access to every thing in C#. It should go without saying c++ should be managing the memory.

Comment: @Taekahn Thank you for the input but is it really necessary to add a third layer? Seems it would slow things down and be harder to manage if anything.

Comment: It’s probably not necessary. No. I’m sure there is a way to get invoke to do what you want. Most likely what is happening is the value is getting boxed/wrapped. I’ve messed around with pinvoke before and in the end I decided to do a middle shim layer and was happy with it. It’s my goto now for c# and c++ interop

Comment: @Taekahn Thanks again, If I don't get an answer to the question between C#/C++ directly, I may resort to the C++/CLI layer, though I'm worried about the maintenance and performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

From C# side, you can bring all the relative memory address offsets of all fields of object instance into C++ and access them by using the offsets added to their object adresses and cast to their POD types.

Then your C++ class would be made of only pointers directly pointing to the C# object fields.

```
struct TestStruct {

    // points to relevant field
    int* myElement;
};

TestStruct t({ptr_from_csharp});
*t.myElement=5; // pinned C# object's field changes
```

If you need the opposite, then C++-side doesn't require the extra pinning operation since it doesn't have GC.

If you don't want to fiddle with pointer type fields, then you can overload getter/setter of fields on C# and run the C++ DLL in those getter/setter methods so that it looks like C# owns the memory from outside but actually only changes the C++-space memory.

```
class TestStruct {
    public int myElement {
        get { return cpp("C++");} 
        set { cpp("change C++");}
    }
};
```

But this would bring interop overhead.

Comment: My goal is the latter, C# referencing objects in C++ memory. So, to understand, I can't edit data directly, I need to call functions in the C++ from the C# to modify the memory in the C++ side?

Answer (score 0):

I would write some kind of awk or perl script that reads the C# class and spits out the required C++ struct.

To this end, it would be helpful to:

- annotate or bracket the C# class(es) with comments that the script recognises and uses to identify said class(es)
- move the C++ struct(s) to a separate header file

Then, when a C# class changes, just run the script on the relevant file(s) and recompile your C++ code.

Don't forget to have the script write out a comment the the effect that the output file is machine-generated so that you don't inadvertently hand-edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Paul. I might just do this but the opposite way around because my main code is in C++. But this doesn't really answer my question, in which I can't get changes to sync through each side

Comment: In what way does it not answer your question?  What form of tooling are you using to propagate such a change automatically?

Comment: Automatic tooling is something I'm a long way away from making and would require significant development or adjustment to achieve. Plus I'm not sure if I need it. I'm just trying to understand the basics of C#/C++ interop and how to edit memory represented by a class shared between managed and unmanaged code. I can't write any scripts to automate that if I don't know how to do it un-automated.

Comment: I think his question is about the actual object in memory, not the code files

Comment: @Taekahn Correct, it is about objects in memory

Comment: @Taekahn I think you and the OP might be at cross-purposes here.  As I understand it, the problem is keeping the C++ `struct` and the C# `class` in sync _in the source code_.  If that is not maintained, then Bad Things Will Happen at runtime.  If the IDE (Visual Studio?) won't do it then some kind of roll-your-own solution is called for, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you but that wasn't my actual problem! Appreciate it regardless.